# Show buttons when canvas being gazed at

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I am creating an app using OculusVR.

I have a canvas which has a number of buttons. I wish these buttons to appear only when the user looks down at that area.

The "cursor" appears when I gaze at the canvas. However, I need to be able to activate the buttons when the user gazes. I want them not to be visible before that.

How can I detect the event of the user gazing there so that I can activate the buttons?

Comment: Raycast from the center of the camera.

Comment: you would actually need to create a timer and If the mouse/pointer is stationary for a few seconds then you can activate the gaze function/method.

Comment: What I can't work out is how to know that this canvas is being gazed at. If it gazes at a button then the button is clicked. What happens when u gaze at a canvas besides the spinner appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the OculusVR works with Unity's `EventSystem` you could do something like the following:

Add an `Image` to your `Canvas` with opacity set to 0, scale it to fit the entire canvas. This will be your triggering element, it must always be enabled so that `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject` returns true.

Attach the script below, drag your `Canvas` object to the `Target` member and your `Image` object to the `Trigger` member.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class UITouch : MonoBehaviour {

/// <summary>
/// Your main canvas
/// </summary>
public Canvas Target;

/// <summary>
/// A UI element that must remain active to make IsPointerOverGameObject true;
/// </summary>
public GameObject Trigger;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        foreach(Transform child in Target.transform)
        {
            child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Transform child in Target.transform)
        {   
            // Make sure not to hide the triggering element
            if (child.gameObject == Trigger) continue;
            child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
}
```